# Convert data types in JSON from Kafka Sparkstreaming

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have a JSON which I am reading from a kafka topic using spark streaming

```
{"COUNTRY_REGION": "United States",  "GROCERY_AND_PHARMACY_CHANGE_PERC": "-7", "PARKS_CHANGE_PERC": "\\\\N",  "LAST_UPDATE_DATE": "05:31.7"}
```

I understand that we would first need to create a schema which I have done here and parse the input json which we got from Kafka i.e. value field via the from_json function.

```
schema = StructType([ 
    StructField("COUNTRY_REGION",StringType(),True), 
    StructField("PROVINCE_STATE",StringType(),True),
    StructField("ISO_3166_1",StringType(),True), 
    StructField("ISO_3166_2", StringType(), True), 
    StructField("DATE", DateType(), True), 
    StructField("GROCERY_AND_PHARMACY_CHANGE_PERC", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("PARKS_CHANGE_PERC", IntegerType(), True), 
    StructField("RESIDENTIAL_CHANGE_PERC", IntegerType(), True), 
    StructField("RETAIL_AND_RECREATION_CHANGE_PERC", IntegerType(), True),                    
    StructField("TRANSIT_STATIONS_CHANGE_PERC", IntegerType(), True),  
    StructField("WORKPLACES_CHANGE_PERC", IntegerType(), True), 
    StructField("LAST_UPDATE_DATE", DateType(), True),
    StructField("LAST_REPORTED_FLAG", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("SUB_REGION_2", StringType(), True),
  ])

json_edit = df.select (from_json("value",schema).alias("json"))
```

However, I realise the `GROCERY_AND_PHARMACY_CHANGE_PERC`, `PARKS_CHANGE_PERC` and `LAST_UPDATE_DATE` become null.

```
display(json_edit)

{"COUNTRY_REGION": "United States",  "GROCERY_AND_PHARMACY_CHANGE_PERC": null, "PARKS_CHANGE_PERC": null, "LAST_UPDATE_DATE": null}
```

I realized that it's because of the original JSON, for example `"GROCERY_AND_PHARMACY_CHANGE_PERC": "-7"` when it should be `"GROCERY_AND_PHARMACY_CHANGE_PERC": -7`.

Is there any way to convert the string to a double/int before I parse it into the schema?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure about schema of incoming data better not to specify it in first place. Well, we can handle this kind situation if we use [schema registry](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/index.html) with data format as avro while [integrating spark with kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882723/integrating-spark-structured-streaming-with-the-confluent-schema-registry).

Since the format is JSON here, we can dynamically extract schema using `schema_of_json` function and pass this output to `from_json`.

Here is code using scala, hope you can change that to python as required.

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  def dfOps(ds: DataFrame, n: Long) =
    ds.select(from_json('value,
      schema_of_json(ds.select('value).first().getString(0))).as("json"))
      .select("json.*").show()

  spark.readStream.format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "mytopic")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .load()
    .select('value.cast("string"))
    .writeStream
    .foreachBatch(dfOps _)
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type of the three columns to `StringType` in the `schema`, parse the json and then process the three columns individually later:

```python
df=...

schema = StructType([ 
    StructField("COUNTRY_REGION",StringType(),True), 
    StructField("PROVINCE_STATE",StringType(),True),
    StructField("ISO_3166_1",StringType(),True), 
    StructField("ISO_3166_2", StringType(), True), 
    StructField("DATE", DateType(), True), 
    StructField("GROCERY_AND_PHARMACY_CHANGE_PERC", StringType(), True), #using StringType
    StructField("PARKS_CHANGE_PERC", StringType(), True), #using StringType
    StructField("RESIDENTIAL_CHANGE_PERC", IntegerType(), True), 
    StructField("RETAIL_AND_RECREATION_CHANGE_PERC", IntegerType(), True),                    
    StructField("TRANSIT_STATIONS_CHANGE_PERC", IntegerType(), True),  
    StructField("WORKPLACES_CHANGE_PERC", IntegerType(), True), 
    StructField("LAST_UPDATE_DATE", StringType(), True), #using StringType
    StructField("LAST_REPORTED_FLAG", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("SUB_REGION_2", StringType(), True),
  ])
df2=df.select (from_json("value",schema).alias("json"))
```

After parsing the json string, convert the struct into separate top-level columns (`select("json.*")`), process the three columns using [withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html) and then repack the struct using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65180650/2129801) if necessary:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2.select("json.*") \
    .withColumn("GROCERY_AND_PHARMACY_CHANGE_PERC", 
        F.col("GROCERY_AND_PHARMACY_CHANGE_PERC").cast(IntegerType())) \
    .withColumn("PARKS_CHANGE_PERC", 
        F.col("PARKS_CHANGE_PERC").cast(IntegerType())) \
    .withColumn("LAST_UPDATE_DATE", 
        F.to_timestamp("LAST_UPDATE_DATE", "HH:mm.s")) \
    .withColumn('json', F.struct(*[F.col(col) for col in df2.select('json.*').columns])) \
    .drop(*df2.select('json.*').columns) \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

*Remark*: in the example data for the column `LAST_UPDATE_DATE` the string `"05:31.7"` is given. The code above assumes that this is a timestamp in the format `HH:mm.s`. As the date is missing the result is `1970-01-01 05:31:07` for this example. This can be fixed using another date format in [to_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp.html).

Comment: I keep getting a  Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();

when i try and run the df2 = df2.select("json.*") \

Comment: I managed to do it like this: 

json_edit = json_edit.select("json.*") \
    .withColumn("GROCERY_AND_PHARMACY_CHANGE_PERC", 
        F.col("GROCERY_AND_PHARMACY_CHANGE_PERC").cast(IntegerType())) \
    .withColumn("PARKS_CHANGE_PERC", 
        F.col("PARKS_CHANGE_PERC").cast(IntegerType())) \
    .withColumn("DATE", 
        F.to_date("DATE","yyyy-MM-dd")) \
    .withColumn("LAST_UPDATE_DATE", 
        F.to_timestamp("LAST_UPDATE_DATE", "HH:mm.s")) \
    .withColumn('json', F.struct(*[F.col(col) for col in json_edit.select('json.*').columns]))\

json_edit = json_edit.drop('json')

Comment: I cant seem to caste date to date.    

 .withColumn("DATE", 
        F.to_date("DATE","yyyy-MM-dd")) \

keeps showing null. Any idea?

Comment: @Adam the format string in `to_date` probably does not match your data. Can you check if your data matches the [datetime pattern](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html) `yyyy-MM-dd`?